# Could not get unknown property 'processReleaseGoogleServices'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I updated to use Android Studio 2.2 and Gradle 2.2.0.  And now I have a problem building.

I followed this post https://medium.com/google-cloud/automatic-per-variant-google-services-json-configurations-with-gradle-d3d3e40abc0e#.g1p7c1tx2 to configure two "google-services.json" files to be used for dev vs prod builds and use the following method in my app/build.gradle file to toggle between the copying the two "google-services.json" files.

```
afterEvaluate {
    processDebugGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToDebug
    processReleaseGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToRelease
}

task switchToDebug(type: Copy) {
    description = 'Switches to DEBUG google-services.json'
    from "src/gcm-dev"
    include "google-services.json"
    into "."
}

task switchToRelease(type: Copy) {
    description = 'Switches to RELEASE google-services.json'
    from "src/gcm-prod"
    include "google-services.json"
    into "."
}
```

Gradle complies fine but when I click on the "Run app" (triangle "play" icon) or "Debug app" (triangle "play" icon with a bug behind) buttons in Android Studio, I get the following:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'processReleaseGoogleServices' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.
```

Please help, much appreciated.

Comment: I got same question after update to Android Studio 2.2

Comment: I just got the same problem after I update Android Studio 2.2

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and problem was in enabled instant run.Try to disable it and run again.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to this is to refer to the task in the following way:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
        task.dependsOn 'switchToDebug'
    } else if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        task.dependsOn 'switchToRelease'
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The problem you mentioned in comment is related to your `google-services.json` file. You need to place `google-services.json` into `app/ dir`. And for each build type there should be accordant director in `app/src` folder.
If file already exists check if correct package name inside it

```
"client_info": {
"mobilesdk_app_id": "1:6596814400689:android:65d6f25f5006145",
"android_client_info": {
  "package_name": "com.my.app.package.name"
}
```

Comment: doesn't work - I get the following:  


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name

Comment: @user1465656 check my update please. Problem is related to `google-services.json`

Answer (score 1):

You should update Google Play Services gradle plugin as well, follow the documentation to set it up: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

The great thing is that you no longer need to write gradle tasks which create appropriate `google-services.json` files in your root directory. Build type specific `google-services.json` are now supported by the plugin:

> "As of version 2.2.0 the plugin supports build type and product flavor
>   specific JSON files. All of the following directory structures are
>   valid"

Answer (score 1):

As described by @Singed, add a directory pr build type/flavor under src-directory and the corresponding `google-services.json`and [Google Play gradle plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) will take care of the rest, e.g.:

```
src/
    debug/google-services.json
    release/google-services.json
```

During build the correct file will be processed, ending up in `build/generated/res/google-services/debug|release/values/values.xml`